# HTML load in UIWebView Crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am trying to load html inside a `UIWebView`. The html content is loading successfully but the content of html is not responsive in the `UIWebView` and when I tap the play button in video content, QuickPlayer shows video content but when I try repeat this action my application crashes with this error:

> WebThread (16): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x115966d50)

Where is my problem in load content?

This is my code for load html:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    webView.frame = view.bounds
    script = "<html><div id=154359904185542><script type=text/JavaScript src=https://www.aparat.com/embed/15stT?data[rnddiv]=154359904185542&data[responsive]=yes></script></div></html>"
    webView.delegate = self
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
      self.webView.loadHTMLString(script, baseURL:nil)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using `WKWebView`, use code below:

```
let wkWebView = WKWebView()
wkWebView.loadHTMLString(""<html><div id=154359904185542><script type=text/JavaScript src=https://www.aparat.com/embed/15stT?data[rnddiv]=154359904185542&data[responsive]=yes></script></div></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

If you are using `UIWebView`, use code below:

```
let webView = UIWebView()
webView.loadHTMLString(""<html><div id=154359904185542><script type=text/JavaScript src=https://www.aparat.com/embed/15stT?data[rnddiv]=154359904185542&data[responsive]=yes></script></div></html>", baseURL: nil)
```

Comment: Your code is exactly the same as my code,What is different?